# Data Trigger Binding Issue (with Int and Enum)

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

All -

Need some insight into this issue. I have created a sample project to isolate the issue on one of my projects. I am trying to set the background of my Border based on a certain value in the model (Int/String/Enum).

The issue I am having is:

1) I believe the source in the DataTrigger Binding is being set - but I am still getting this error:
*personId property not found on 'object' ''String'. BindingExpression:Path=personId; DataItem='String' (HashCode=1896530089); target element is 'Border' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')*

2) I was doing this on int (or string) just to make the concept work. But realistically I need to make this of the Enum value. any suggestions on this will also help.

Here are the code snippets:

Person.cs

```
public class Person
{
    public int personId { get; set; }
    public string personName { get; set; }
    public Gender personType { get; set; }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
}
```

PersonViewModel.cs

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> people
    {
        get
        {
            return _people;
        }
    }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person()
            {
                personId = 1,
                personName = "John",
                personType = Person.Gender.Male
            },

            new Person()
            {
                personId = 1,
                personName = "Mary",
                personType = Person.Gender.Female
            },
        };
    }
}
```

PersonView.xaml.cs

```
public PersonView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         var personvm = new PersonViewModel();
        DataContext = personvm;
    }
```

PersonView.xaml

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BorderGradient" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source=people, Path=personId}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.511,0.957">
                            <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.55" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1.3" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source=people, Path=personId}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.511,0.957">
                            <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0.55" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="1.3" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Border CornerRadius="15,15,15,15" Style="{StaticResource BorderGradient}" >
    <Grid Width="Auto" MinWidth="750" Height="Auto" MinHeight="600">

<!-- Logic in VM where visibility would be set through VM -->

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="To be set" >
            <loc:MaleView/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Visibility=" to be set">
            <loc:FemaleView />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: Patrick, it's not really clear what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate on what you're expecting to happen? Can you show how you're binding to the ObservableCollection of People?

Comment: Sure. Editing my post above to show the real use-case above

Comment: Patrick, You're wanting to change the border that the datagrid is contained when a Person in the People collection is equal to a certain value? If that's the case then you're going about this wrong. You need a property on the PersonViewModel that the Style can bind to that indicates that the background color should change, or whatever. If you're trying to change the background color of a single row in the datagrid (bound to a Person), then create a DataGridRow style and set the trigger that way.

Comment: Michael - Sorry - I realized in simplfying the exammple to highlight the issue - i may have got the wrong context. The context is such - Each person is shown through a user control (singular) and I want to change the background of the window based on the person - male or female. Ofcourse I pasted the data grid on the top - which means all are shown in the same view - which will not be the case. Updating the code too

Comment: "Each person is shown through a user control". So you want each user control that represents a person to have the background color reflect the gender of the person. The usercontrol should be have the DataContext of "Person", right? Then copy the style into the usercontrol, and specify the source of the binding to DataContext.

Comment: Mike - updated the code to highlight the use-case. But here is my problem - the border and shade to be set is in the PersonView (which has the datacontext set up of personviewmodel) - but the usercontrol will have the controls which will display the data. So essentially I am trying to set the border in the mainwindow - even though the inner grid actually renders the details of the person.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16790/discussion-between-michael-g-and-patrick)

Comment: Posting an image of the exact problem. Mike - am in the chat room - when you have a chance - can you please join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

people is an observable collection, which is what you're binding to in your datatrigger. The ObservableCollection doesn't have a property named "personId".

It would probably be better to have a DataTemplate for your PersonViewModel

```
<DataTemplate DataType={x:Type vm:PersonViewModel}">

   <Grid Background="Red">
         .. Template For PersonViewModel Here ..
   </Grid>

   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=personId}" Value="1">
         .... do stuff
      </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike - Any suggestion on how do i reach one level down and get the personid (of the person object). I ofcourse dont want to hardcode people[0]. Should i have an iterator over the data trigger then (data template??)

Comment: @Patrick You need to either use a control meant to display a list of objects such as an `ItemsControl`, or bind your control to a single instance of the `Person` object (such as `people[0]`) instead of binding to a collection of them.